# Saving check box values to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I allow users to group contacts together using checkboxes in the new and edit forms:

```
<% current_user.contacts.all.each do |contact| %>
    <% checked = @group.contacts.include?(contact) %>
    <%= check_box_tag "contacts[]", contact.id, checked %>
    <%= f.label contact.name %>
<% end %>
```

Until recently, I was able to use the following code in create action to create a group:

```
def create
        @group = current_user.groups.new(group_params)
        @contacts = Contact.find(params[:contacts])
        @group.contacts << @contacts
        if @group.save
        ......
end
```

To ensure that already checked values aren't added to a group during the update action, I used a hidden tag in the form.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "contacts[]",'' %>
<% current_user.contacts.all.each do |contact| %>
    <% checked = @group.contacts.include?(contact) %>
    <%= check_box_tag "contacts[]", contact.id, checked %>
     <%= f.label contact.name %>
<% end %>
```

Now, I'm unable to create or update a group as the hidden_field value is also passed along. An Active Record not found : Couldn't find all Contacts with 'id': (, 3, 4) (found 2 results, but was looking for 3) error. How can I solve this?

Comment: You want the `hidden_field_tag` above your loop.  Which version of rails are you running?

Comment: and also if you are expecting multiple ids like now, you can do  `Contact.find_all_by_id(params[:contacts])`

Comment: @japed sorry, I made a mistake. The hidden_field is already above the loop. Edited the code to reflect this. And, I'm using Rails 4.1

Comment: @nithin I'm getting 'undefined method `find_all_by_id'' in that case.

Comment: `params[:contacts]` values after form submission? and why is that hidden field used, are you trying to create an empty array then do `<%= contacts = Array.new %>`

Comment: @nithin I don't get your first question. Using the hidden_field to display which contacts are already checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the hidden field tag to be nil rather than an empty string

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "contacts[]", nil %>
```

But as you're using rails 4 then collection_check_boxes might be of [interest](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)